# progress bar in android

Tags: android

my progress bar is show but not move horizontal. Here is my code :

```
 package com.net.pvr;

 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLConnection;

 import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.os.Message;
 import android.util.Log;

public class HTTPLocation implements Runnable {
private static HTTPLocation instance;


private ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;
private ByteArrayBuffer baf;
private Activity activity;
public String url;
public String id;
private HTTPLocation()
{
}
public Activity getActivity() {
    return activity;
}

public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}


private Handler handler;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}


public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public static HTTPLocation getInstance() {

        instance = new HTTPLocation();
        return instance;
}

  public void init() {


    myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    myProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    myProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(5);
    myProgressDialog.setMax(100);

        Thread t = new Thread(this);

    t.start();

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        String url1 = this.getUrl();
        System.out.println("url "+url1);
        URL url = new URL(url1);

        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1000);            
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        bis.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


        if(baf!=null){
            bundle.putByteArray("data", baf.toByteArray());
        }else{
            bundle.putByteArray("data", null);  
        }

        Message messagepush = Message.obtain();
        messagepush.what = 200;
        messagepush.setData(bundle);
        messagepush.setTarget(handler);
        myProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
        messagepush.sendToTarget();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem try using `AsyncTask`Threads can be easily handled through it and prorgress dialog will work perfectly.

```
    private  class className extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
              // your function

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
        loadingProgress.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        loadingProgress = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "", "Please wait...",true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code from google:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

You should put your code which updates the progress bar here `onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)` .

You can read more about it here [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and here [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) .

You should update UI elements only on the UI thread or use `AsyncTask` class or `Handler`.